# Does Ubuntu One effected by NSA according what Edward Snowden published?

Tags: ubuntu-one, security

It is very important for me to keep my files in a safe Host. I use ubuntu one because of ease of using in Ubuntu. You think is it safe enough of spying ?

Comment: the problem with this is that anyone that has access to a router which traffic goes through it can "spy" on users so having a secure  host isn't the main problem...

Comment: so you mean someone who controls the router, is able to control any host?

Comment: no they can access any data that comes through there. So spied can you always be by anyone, keep that in mind.

Comment: I recommend getting a webhost and creating your own cloud storage. Nothing is truly secure, but if you access that via a VPN you can get pretty close.

Comment: I just don't care that they can access my files, if they really want to then they can do it in anyway, so why bother? don't have so sensitive information on a computer that has access to a network...

Comment: My main point is that if they really want to know what you ate for breakfast they can, but for the most part nobody cares. So don't go all "I need maximum security on everything?!?!?!?!", just don't.

Comment: @Alvar This might apply to personal data, but for companies it's of great importance not to become victim to industrial espionage.

Comment: @Soulsource We aren't talking about industrial espionage, we are talking storage for personal data, nothing else...

Comment: @Alvar: If the focus is especially on you, those agencies will probably succeed, but the price to to get to your data will raise enormously, compared to a mass screening. Most attacks you're vulnerable don't scale. And the more people resist simple observance, the more expensive it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One) and the results of Whois and GeoIP lookups, the Ubuntu One servers are located in Great Britain, which is definitely not the worst location to have servers, since it is inside EU, meaning that there are relatively strong privacy security laws in effect, and that it's a partner country grade 2 ([source](http://derstandard.at/1371171050253/NSA-stuft-Deutschland-als-Angriffsziel-ein)) of the USA, meaning it's explicitly excluded from their systematic data theft and industrial espionage (at least, officially).

The transmission of data to the Ubuntu One servers is done using [SSL](https://one.ubuntu.com/privacy/), meaning that it's reasonably secure, at least if you use the web interface and **check the used security certificate** (the NSA and other industrial espionage agencies have the wrong to have certificates for TLDs issued, allowing Man-In-The-Middle attacks if one doesn't check the certificate used).

Nevertheless, Ubuntu One stores files [unencrypted](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/are-my-files-stored-on-the-server-encrypted/), to enable the user to publish them over it. So, if for any reason a British court decides that Ubuntu One has to give data to the police, the police will get the files and will be able to read them without problems.

Therefore, it is strongly recommended to encrypt any data before it gets uploaded to Ubuntu One (or any other cloud storage). You can either do this manually (for instance with gpg or openssl), or use an automated solution. Someone reported that he used [encfs with Ubuntu One](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+question/74734#comment-2) successfully.

Comment: Informative, but in no way authorative. ***Don't forget: encrypting your data will draw attention.***

Comment: If you had followed the news, GB is the worst place to store your data. Only the second (SSL) and last paragraph (encrypt your data) are valuable.

Comment: Yes, the British intellegency service MI6 helped the United States to spy the data of European users. Therefore, placing the server in GB is as worst as in the United States.